# How to add icons to input fields if the field has not passed validation

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, css, form-validation

I need to add a custom icon to the floor if the field does not pass validation, as in the screenshot.

[image]

I tried to implement this functionality with ':after' in CSS

```
    &._error .control input {
        &:after {
            content: 'X';
            color: #000;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    }
```

but the item is not displayed on the frontend

[image]